# Android: Display a pop-up dialog when a particular word in a TextView is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

In my application, I have some text for terms and conditions.

> By registering you agree to be bound by our Terms of Use and that you have read our Privacy Policy.

The words *Terms of Use* and *Privacy Policy* should be clickable, and display an alert box.

First I tried splitting the sentences into four `TextView`s:

1. By registering you agree to be bound by our
2. Terms of Use
3. and that you have read our
4. Privacy Policy.

This worked well, with the following layout XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/termsandcondtion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/terms_1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="showTerms"
            android:text="@string/terms_2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/terms_3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/termsofuse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="showTermsofUse"
            android:text="@string/terms_4"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The code for displaying the popup is:

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    wv.loadUrl(url);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Privacy Policy");
    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

The problem is that the four `TextView`s are not properly aligned with each other.
This means I have to use one `TextView` and display a pop-up diaplog when a particular word (Terms of Use, Privacy Policy) in `TextView` is clicked.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think ClickableSpan would help me..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you will need `Spannable Strings`. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words) question would help. Creating [`ClickableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) will be a good choice for your problem.

```
SpannableString stringToSpan = new SpannableString("<your sentence>");
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.<yourTextView ID>);
textView.setText(stringToSpan);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View textView) {
       //alert box code here
       }
      };
stringToSpan.setSpan(clickableSpan, <start position of span>,<end position>,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   }
```

Comment: Good suggestion , but make it as a good answer by explaining a bit in code dude

Comment: @ManojKumar: The link in the answer has the code. Nevertheless, the code has been added.

Comment: @Nerd I want to display terms.html when Terms of Use clicked, at the same time privacy.html for Privacy Policy

Comment: URL gets dynamically changed reg the words clicked