# How a mobile message make a phone number clickable?

Tags: android

I am sending message from web application to android mobile which contains some mobile number, But that mobile number is not clickable to set calls from there.

Comment: share text what you are sending in SMS.

Comment: "I am sending message" >> what kind of message ? SMS ? GCM ?

Comment: Thanks bro for replying, text i am sending is "my number is +10XXXXXX" to my users but the number is not clickable from there message box.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

if you can use TextView,

there is two way of autolink

1) Linkify in JavaCode

ex>

```
public class LinkifyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView txtPhone1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone1);
        Linkify.addLinks(txtPhone1, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);

        TextView txtPhone2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone2);
        Linkify.addLinks(txtPhone2, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);

        TextView txtWeb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWeb);
        Linkify.addLinks(txtWeb, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    }
}
```

all    => Linkify.ALL

e-mail      => Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES

address         => Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES

web URL => Linkify.WEB_URLS

**phonenumber    => Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS**

2) AutoLink in xml

ex>

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtAutoWeb"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:autoLink="phone"
  android:text="01012341234" />
```

the number is not contain -(hyphen), it dosen't matter.

Comment: The intent is to show the SMS clickable and not a link in the app as clickable

Comment: @Ranjith  hmm.. are you looking for like [this](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links)? i hope is it helpful..

Answer (score 0):

you may use `SpannableString` and/or `SpannableStringBuilder`

here is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words) about it

and here [is Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) about it

so you may need to send your message separated with special separator
then add it to textView wrapped in SpannableString 
ex, `data bla bla#SEP#+963xxxxxxx#SP#data2 bla bla`

so you get this String and split it, and apply SpannableString

```
String msg = getMsgFromServer();
String msgParts[] = msg .split("#SEP#");
```

check qustion above to complete , it has handling for `onClick` on each spannable item.