# Tap word and copy it from TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I`d like to copy a word to the buffer from TextView by tap on this word.

As example:
My TextView is "Hello world. This is summer".

Is there way to tap "summer" and get it in the buffer?

I know that I can copy string of TextView, but I need to have only one word.

Comment: Look into clickable span, it allows individual words to be clicked inside a textview

Comment: thanks, but I have long text and I must copy all words which I click, not just one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words

Comment: thanks, it doesn't suit me, i can't set a clickable part for each word. =(

Comment: did you find a way to mark the selected word? if yes post your code so we could build on it

Comment: I have 1000 words in TextView, I don't need to mark it, I need to copy that word which I pressed.